# I want to change the background color on chars in a textbox after chars in textarea are more then 150 chars

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I'm using `event.data` to get text that I'm typing in [this HTML textbox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIoHa.png), and I want to color the background to red, but the attribute style on `event.data` is giving me error. I'm not using jQuery.

```js
textarea.addEventListener('input', function( event ) {
    if( length > maxLength ) {
        console.log(event.data);
    }
    // ...
}
```

I would need [something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJYQf.png).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You should share your code, not screenshot *!*

Answer (score 1):

```js
let input = document.getElementById('input');
input.addEventListener( 'keyup', event => {
  if( event.target.value.length > 150 )
    console.log('text is >150 chars')
});
```

```html
<textarea id='input'>

</textarea>
```

If you want to highlight text, I don't think you can do that in a textarea. At least not without selecting the text.

PS: Using `contenteditable` on an element may allow this kind of behavior to work, but I would not recommend it; you will have non-form elements in your form.

Comment: not the solution, he's dealing with text not numbers

Comment: @Endless You are correct. I modified the answer a little to handle a `textarea` :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [maxlength](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/maxlength) attribute so they simply can't use more 150 chars

`<textarea maxlength="150"></textarea>`

if they do manage to insert more then 150 chars for some reason, then you could use [:invalid](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:invalid) [pseudo-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes)

```
:invalid {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have what i want thanks you

> function handleRedBackground() {  var cointainer =
>   document.getElementById("red-background");    var paragraph =
>   container.children[0];    var transparent = String( textarea.value
>   ).slice(0, tweetLength );     var highlighted = String( textarea.value
>   ).slice( tweetLength );
>
> container.height = textarea.offSetHeight;   paragraph.style.top = (-1
>   * parseInt( textarea.scrollTop)) + "px";
>
> paragraph.innerHTML = "" + transparent + "**" +
>   highlighted + "**"; }

Answer (score 0):

if you enter more than however much you want the text color becomes red, is this what you want if not explain more, please.

```
function h() {    // this function will be invoced by oninput from the textbox
   if ( length > maxLength ){
      consol.log(event.data);  
      document.getElementById('your textbox id').style.color = "red";
   }

}
```